# How can I correct a negative tendency of residuals?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, cart, boosting

I ran few algorithms on a continuous target variable. I have 40,000 observation for training and 5000 observations in out-of-sample. I used linear regression, decision tree and xgboost. All of them gave me residuals that when I averaged them or aggregate show a strong negative bias toward the target variable.
How can I fix it and what is the cause for this?
Here are the residuals results:

Target variable plot:[image]

```
    Linear regression   Model.Xgboost   Model.decisionTree
Avg.    -16.77700338    -16.76011315    -16.97068065
Sum      -124166.602    -124041.5974    -125600.0075
```

Residuals plot:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a constant term in your regressions?

Comment: If the meaning variables that are with very low sd. then yes.

Comment: No, I mean on the right hand side of your equations: $y = a + b*x$, $a$ is a constant term.  In linear regression, if you have a constant term, the mean of the residuals is guaranteed to equal 0, whence my question.

Comment: Hello @jbowman, the answer is no, I don't see such terms.

Comment: If you don't see a constant term, you can easily get large average errors.  If you can add a constant term and rerun your models, the average error should become zero.  I may expand this point and post as an answer later on, unless someone else does so first.

Comment: Hello @jbowman, would be great to have an example as an answare. If I understand you correctly, this constant term is not dinamic so if we will get a different dataset to train and as out-of-sample we may get a constant error.Am I right?

Comment: I will put one together later today (it's early morning where I am now...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure the data you have but it may contain outliers that are very far from the normal observations. You can check for outliers through cook's distance. It will measure the tendency of the prediction to change when a particular observation is omitted from the data. For detail of cook's distance please see the link below.

http://www.statisticshowto.com/cooks-distance/

Comment: Thanks @ahmedrajput, but it seems that most ( about 90% of residuals) are below the "0" line. Also, I have 40,000 observation for training and 5000 observations in out-of-sample.

Comment: Have you standardised the data before applying the regression methods?

Comment: No, this is a good point to check.

Comment: The scale didn't help but i think that the target variable's plot reveal that there are two groups inside it,